# create a new column within a select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, case

Heres the code im using.

```
 select address, area,
 case area
 when area < 1500 then 'small'
 when area > 2500 then 'large'
 else 'medium'
 end as size
 from listings
 where zip = 95677;
```

With this i want to create a new column that will tell you whether a house is big or small depending on the area size.

This is the error i get and im not really sure how to cast it to make it work. If that is the solution to it like the hint says.

> LINE 3:  when area < 1500 then 'small'
>            ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: `case when area ...` instead of `case area when area ...`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
 select address, area,
        (case when area < 1500 then 'small'
              when area > 2500 then 'large'
              else 'medium'
         end) as size
 from listings
 where zip = 95677;
```

`case` has two forms.  The above is the `case when <condition>` form, where the `when` clauses are fully formed conditions.  The other form is more like a switch statement in C:  `case area when 10 then 'ten' when 20 then 'twenty' . . .`.  This form can only test for equality of a single expression.